# How can I query raw via Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to do a query in my Laravel app and I want to use a normal structure for my query. This class either does use Eloquent so I need to find something to do a query totally raw.

Might be something like `Model::query($query);`. Only that doesn't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use `DB::statement('your raw query here')`. Hope this helps.

Comment: This will return a boolean if the statement is a select, for select clauses use DB::select to get an array of raw results.

Comment: You should use DB::statement only when you do not expect any output of query.

Comment: this is not eloquent

Comment: The answer is wrong. 1 `DB` is a QueryBuilder, not Eloquent. 2. `DB::statement` executes statement and returns boolean, so it is not useful when you need to retrieve data.

Comment: The answer is wrong.
This is not eloquent, but DB::statement is a Query Builder.

Answer (score 98):

You may try this:

```
// query can't be select * from table where
Model::select(DB::raw('query'))->get();
```

An Example:

```
Model::select(DB::raw('query'))
     ->whereNull('deleted_at')
     ->orderBy('id')
     ->get();
```

Also, you may use something like this (Using Query Builder):

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
                 ->where('status', '<>', 1)
                 ->groupBy('status')
                 ->get();
```

Also, you may try something like this  (Using Query Builder):

```
$users = DB::select('select * from users where id = ?', array(1));
$users = DB::select( DB::raw("select * from users where username = :username"), array('username' => Input::get("username")));
```

Check more about `Raw-Expressions` on [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions).

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for a complete query. And, Im using the Eloquent thing, not the DB. Does that matter?

Comment: On `Eloquent` you can't use complete raw query but you may use all the methods' of `Query Builder` with `Eloquent`.

Comment: `use DB;` if DB is not found

Comment: Why can't the query be like `select * from table`? For security reasons?

Comment: @CarloRodríguez add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

Answer (score 41):

You can use `hydrate()` function to convert your array to the Eloquent models, which `Laravel` itself *internally* uses to convert the query results to the models. It's not mentioned in the docs as far as I know.

Below code is equviolent to `$userModels = User::where('id', '>', $userId)->get();`:

```
$userData = DB::select('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id > ?', [$userId]);
$userModels = User::hydrate($userData);
```

`hydrate()` function is defined in `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` as:

```
/**
 * Create a collection of models from plain arrays.
 *
 * @param  array  $items
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public function hydrate(array $items) {}
```

Answer (score 13):

I don't think  you can by default. I've extended Eloquent and added the following method.

```
/**
 * Creates models from the raw results (it does not check the fillable attributes and so on)
 * @param array $rawResult
 * @return Collection
 */
public static function modelsFromRawResults($rawResult = [])
{
    $objects = [];

    foreach($rawResult as $result)
    {
        $object = new static();

        $object->setRawAttributes((array)$result, true);

        $objects[] = $object;
    }

    return new Collection($objects);
}
```

You can then do something like this:

```
class User extends Elegant { // Elegant is my extension of Eloquent

     public static function getWithSuperFancyQuery()
     {
         $result = DB::raw('super fancy query here, make sure you have the correct columns');
         return static::modelsFromRawResults($result);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, it worked me when fixed as $result = DB::select('super fancy query here, make sure you have the correct columns');  In Laravel 5.5

Comment: Eloquent does support this by default. Almost any query can append the word raw to use raw SQL. Such as `selectRaw('count(*) as count')` or `whereRaw('1=1')`.

Answer (score 5):

Old question, already answered, I know.

However, nobody seems to mention the Expression class.

Granted, this might not fix your problem because your question leaves it ambiguous as to where in the SQL the Raw condition needs to be included (is it in the SELECT statement or in the WHERE statement?).  However, this piece of information you might find useful regardless.

Include the following class in your Model file:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;
```

Then inside the Model class define a new variable

```
protected $select_cols = [
    'id', 'name', 'foo', 'bar',
    Expression ('(select count(1) from sub_table where sub_table.x = top_table.x) as my_raw_col'), 'blah'
]
```

And add a scope:

```
public function scopeMyFind ($builder, $id) {
    return parent::find ($id, $this->select_cols);
}
```

Then from your controller or logic-file, you simply call:

```
$rec = MyModel::myFind(1);
dd ($rec->id, $rec->blah, $rec->my_raw_col);
```

Happy days.

(Works in Laravel framework 5.5)

Answer (score 2):

use **Eloquent Model** related to the **query** you're working on.

and do something like this:

```
$contactus = ContactUS::select('*')
    ->whereRaw('id IN (SELECT min(id) FROM users GROUP BY email)')
    ->orderByDesc('created_at')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten your result handling by writing

```
$objects = new Collection(array_map(function($entry) {
    return (new static())->setRawAttributes((array) $entry, true);
}, $result));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select info it is  `DB::select(Statement goes here)` just remember that some queries wont work unless you go to Config/Database.php and set connections = mysql make sure 'strict' = false
Just know that it can cause some security concerns

Answer (score 0):

if ever you might also need this.
orderByRaw() function for your order by.

Like

> WodSection::orderBy('score_type')
>
> ->orderByRaw('FIELD(score_type,"score_type") DESC')
>
> ->get();