# How to get the count of MySQL count occurrences of id in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am using laravel framework. i want to get the count of  MySQL count occurrences of id. Here is my problem. My table name is download_histories. Here is my record for demo :-

```
Table:- download_histories
id   alt_image_id   
1       25  
2       25
3       26
4       27  
5       29
6       26
```

Now look at the table. Now this table having 6 records and alt_image_id 25 coming  twice times and alt_image_id 26 coming twice times .and 27 and 29 coming once .
Now i want the result when group of alt_image count is greater then equal to 2. Now i want the count of groupby records can anyone help me. I want the count that is 2

i have done so far :-

```
DB::table('download_histories')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(download_histories.user_id) as totaluserdownload'))
        ->groupby('alt_image_id')
        ->having('totaluserdownload','>=',2)
        ->get();
```

Note : i want the count not get the data . Please help me. Thanks in advance :)
[image]

Comment: What is the issue with the above query ?

Comment: this gives me count of every group but i want the count of whole group

Comment: @MayankPandeyz i want the count of group by result not each group count

Comment: Try just replacing the ->count() with ->get(), since what you want is to get a number of counts, rather than to count the number of results.

Comment: @JoelHinz get will give me each group count but i want the whole group by count

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood. In that case ->count() looks like the right choice to be honest.

Comment: I want the result simply 2 because 25 and 26 occuring twice in alt_image_id column see

Comment: "select count(1) from (select count(download_histories.user_id) as totaluserdownload from download_histories group by alt_image_id having totaluserdownload >= 2) t1". Not familiar with laravell, possibly it is impossible.

Comment: @degr please implement in laravel eloquent query no core sql query

Comment: @degr your query is right but i want to implement with laravel query

Comment: `DB::table('(select count(download_histories.user_id) as totaluserdownload from download_histories group by alt_image_id having totaluserdownload >= 2) t1')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(1) as totaluserdownload')
        ->get();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925451/how-can-i-query-raw-via-eloquent

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: @kunal Please post complete table structure

Comment: @amit see i have attached the screenshot

Comment: Can you add expected result example?

Comment: According to my above screenshot the result will be count 1 beacuse alt_image id  38 come twice according to my upper above example i want count 2 because alt_image_id  25 and 26 both come twice