# LARAVEL MYSQL how to use natural JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, natural-join

I need a return in collection to paginate but i can only a return in array because the query use a natural JOIN.
How could I do this query using Laravel collections :

> SELECT mensagens.* FROM mensagens NATURAL JOIN (  SELECT   id_emissor, MAX(created_at) created_at  FROM     mensagens WHERE id_receptor = ".$user_id."  GROUP BY id_emissor) t

I have used this code:

> $mensagem =  \DB::select(
>               DB::raw("SELECT mensagens.* FROM mensagens NATURAL JOIN (  SELECT   id_emissor, MAX(created_at) created_at  FROM     mensagens WHERE id_receptor = ".$user_id."  GROUP BY id_emissor) t ")
>               );

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925451/how-can-i-query-raw-via-eloquent

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your query as it is then use like this -

```
\DB::raw("SELECT mensagens.* FROM mensagens NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT id_emissor, MAX(created_at) created_at FROM mensagens WHERE id_receptor = ".$user_id." GROUP BY id_emissor) t");
```

Else you can use eloquent also.