# Raw query from with in the model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to figure out how to run a raw query from within a model.

Let's say I have a model FOO and this model has a method which does cross table joints, grouping a bit more logic and is way to heavy for Eloquent ORM.

What I want is the ability to call this method from controller, like so:

```
Model::method()->get()
```

To be honest, any other call is fine as long as I can keep the raw query inside the model and call it from controller.

What I want to avoid is to have DB::raw() and the query itself in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `static` to the method you can call it directly from the model `Model::method()` else you should use a model instance `$modelInstance->method()` :

So in your model :

```php
public static function method(){
    // your query
    return queryBuilder;
}
```

That's all, and in the controller you can do it like you want :

```
Model::method()->get()
```

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925451/how-can-i-query-raw-via-eloquent

Comment: Thanks Maraboc and Kanna, that worked. Question: is static necessary for model methods? Is this how Eloquent works?

Comment: If you add `static` to the method you can call it directly from the model `Model::method()` else you should use a model instance `$modelInstance->method()`

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way is to do it with laravel Query scope

```
public static function scopeFoo($query)
{
    return $query->whereStatus(...);
}
```

and in controller

```
Model::Foo()->get();
```